# Why new WQA app builds are not identified in the bug, feedback and session details?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

Recently some updates were made into an iOS app build within WQA and new builds were distributed successfully. It is expected to have new/updated build version of the app in the collected data, however, new app build versions are not captured in WQA bug, feedback and session details.

Comment: Please rephrase your text as an actual question. Your text above is not a question and this post is now a candidate for being closed and/or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS the "CFUUIDCreate" method is used to generate a Universally Unique Identifier (UUID). When the back-end detects that this has changed, it checks automatically creates a new version for the application. Small UI changes might not generate a new UUID.

See the following tech note for more information:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21679495